# How to make this removeMiddle test pass when just return 1 value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am trying to create a function to make this test pass

Here is my following code for my test cases:

```
var removeMiddle = require("./remove-middle");

test("Remove middle", function () {
  var words = ["mouse", "giraffe", "queen", "window", "bottle"];

  var expectedWords = ["mouse", "giraffe", "window", "bottle"];
  var expectedOutput = ["queen"];

  var output = removeMiddle(words);

  expect(output).toEqual(expectedOutput);
  expect(words).toEqual(expectedWords);
});
```

Here is my function that I created:

```
function removeMiddle(words) {
  let index = [];
  words.splice(2, 1);
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i] === "queen") {
      index.push(words[i]);
    }
  }

  return words;
}

module.exports = removeMiddle;
```

Right now my function just passed the second test case which is: `expect(words).toEqual(expectedWords);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you expect your output to be the word(s) removed. But you are returning the `words` array from `removeWords`. You probably can return `index`.

Also, once you have spliced your `words` array, **queen** will no more be a part of the array. So your for loop does nothing and index returns an empty array.

You can modify your code like this to get your expected output:

```
function removeMiddle(words) {
  let index = [words[2]];
  words.splice(2, 1);
  return index;
}
```

But right now your code is a little hard coded, works only for a fixed length of array(5). You can do the following if you want a more generic solution.

```
function removeMiddle(words) {
 if(words.length == 0) return [];
  let index = [];
  let middleElements = [];
  if(words.length % 2 == 0){
   console.log(words[Math.floor(words.length/2)]);
    middleElements.push(words[Math.floor(words.length/2)]);
    words.splice(words.length/2,1);
   console.log(words[Math.floor(words.length/2)]);
    middleElements.push(words[Math.floor(words.length/2)]);
    words.splice(words.length/2,1);  
  }
  else{
   console.log(words.length/2);
    middleElements.push(words[Math.floor(words.length/2)]);
    words.splice(words.length/2,1);  
  }
  return middleElements;
}
```